# Which CyanogenMod version should I use on my Transformer Prime?

Tags: cyanogenmod, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have an [Eee Pad Transformer Prime TF201](http://www.asus.com/Tablets/Eee_Pad_Transformer_Prime_TF201/) that is currently running Android Version 4.1.1; however, I am trying to update it to KitKat (hopefully 4.4.2). I found [this guide](http://hdfpga.blogspot.com/2014/02/asus-transformer-prime-tf201-with.html) to help me do that and the provided gapps zip file version is `20131119` but on the [CyanogenMod wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) it says the highest gapps version is `20140105`.

Also, the link provided on the tutorial page for the firmware is `cm-11-20140123-UNOFFICIAL-tf201` but on [Cyano's webpage for the TF201](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Tf201_Info) the most stable version is `cm-9.1.0`.

So I have a few combinations that I can do the tutorial with. Either:

1. Use the latest gapps version (`20140105`) and the provided firmware (`cm-11-20140123-UNOFFICIAL-tf201`)
2. Use the provided gapps version (`20131119`) and the latest stable firmware (`cm-9.1.0`)
3. Use the latest of both
4. Use the provided versions of both

Obviously, I would like everything on my tablet to be the latest version of everything however there must be a reason this tutorial (and another I saw) are providing these outdated versions of the gapps and firmware (unless the posts just haven't been updated). So does anyone know which is the best option (that works) to go with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TF201 isn't supported on CM11, so your choices are to go with official nightlies (which are not stable) of CM10.1 from [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=nightly&device=tf201) or unofficial CM11 from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2589554). Neither of these are stable or officially supported releases.

The Google apps version you should use depends on the CM version you choose to flash. If you're using CM11, use the 20140105 GApps. If you're using CM10.1, use the 20130812 GApps.